# How to sort by month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

[Here is demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b9a4/10/0)

The order is November and October. How can I add ORDER BY to this, so that the order is by month, Jan, Feb, Mar...etc.

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `hw_homework` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `studentid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `subjectid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `teacherid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=55 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `hw_homework`
--

INSERT INTO `hw_homework` (`id`, `studentid`, `subjectid`, `assignment_name`, `teacherid`, `date`) VALUES
(52, 56, 13, '1A', 20, '2012-10-28'),
(53, 56, 6, '12', 18, '2012-10-28'),
(54, 56, 4, 'page42', 59, '2012-11-02');


SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M') `month`,
        COUNT(studentid) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
WHERE studentid = 56
GROUP BY studentid, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M')
```

Comment: why not just *order by date asc*?

Comment: Have you tried "order by MONTH(date)" ?

Answer (score 8):

As Chuidiang suggested I added the following to get what I wanted.
Thanks everyone.

```
ORDER BY Month(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case it is ordering based on aplhabets.
Following will give correct result.

```
SELECT  studentID, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M') `month`,
    COUNT(studentid) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
WHERE studentid = 56
GROUP BY studentid, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this post trying to find the solution to sort by Month name. Probably not very elegant solution, but you can use the [FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) string function to get that result set.

```
SELECT
studentID,
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') `month`,
COUNT(studentid) totalMissed FROM
hw_homework WHERE
studentid = 56 GROUP BY
studentid, 
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') ORDER BY
FIELD(
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M'),
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
);
```

Try that. Also you can perhaps replace DATE_FORMAT with the easier function MONTHNAME(`date`) for readability purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT  studentID, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M') as `month`,
    COUNT(studentid) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
WHERE studentid = 56
order by Month(month)
GROUP BY studentid, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M') `month`,
        COUNT(studentid) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
WHERE studentid = 56
GROUP BY MONTH(DATE) ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

Use as follows in your query

```
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score -1):

mysql> select * from hw_homework order by date asc;  //increasing order

OR

mysql> select * from hw_homework order by date desc;

Comment: You haven't understood what is being asked. Review the other answers to learn more.